# Change color of table boundary caption, label and table contents

Tags: tables, colortbl

Please find the code and the corresponding output below

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{colortbl}
 \begin{document}
\begin{table*}[]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \caption{\textcolor{red}{Pole}}
\label{table5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textcolor{red}{OHO} \\ \textcolor{red}{MF} \\ \textcolor{red}{$P$}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textcolor{red}{OYE}\\ \textcolor{red}{OME}\\ \textcolor{red}{$P$}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textcolor{red}{RA}\\ \textcolor{red}{OY} \\ \textcolor{red}{M}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textcolor{red}{FR}\\ \textcolor{red}{MOO}\\ \textcolor{red}{$M$}\end{tabular} \\\arrayrulecolor{red}  \hline
    \textcolor{red}{-1.5       }                                                                            & \textcolor{red}{-2}                                                                                                         &                                                                                                        &                                                                                      \\ \hline
    \textcolor{red}{-2.1634 + 1.2490i }                                                                                   & \textcolor{red}{-3}                                                                                                         
&                                                                                                        &                                                                                      
\\ \hline
    \textcolor{red}{-2.7     }                                                                              
   & \textcolor{red}{-4}                                                                                                         
      &                                                                                                        
       &                                                                                      
    \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
 \end{table*}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

I want to make all the borders and the contents of the table in red color. However, as seen in the attached figure, the color of the topmost row and column is not coming in color. Also, the color of "Table 1: " is not in red color. So, my query is how to make the complete table in red color?

Comment: If you add `\color{red}` after `\centering` everything will become red.

Comment: Got it. But still "Table 1: " is not coming red. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be happy to remove this but when I compile

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{colortbl}
 \begin{document}
\begin{table*}[]
\centering\color{red}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \caption{\textcolor{red}{Pole}}
\label{table5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textcolor{red}{OHO} \\ \textcolor{red}{MF} \\ \textcolor{red}{$P$}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textcolor{red}{OYE}\\ \textcolor{red}{OME}\\ \textcolor{red}{$P$}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textcolor{red}{RA}\\ \textcolor{red}{OY} \\ \textcolor{red}{M}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textcolor{red}{FR}\\ \textcolor{red}{MOO}\\ \textcolor{red}{$M$}\end{tabular} \\\arrayrulecolor{red}  \hline
    \textcolor{red}{-1.5       }                                                                            & \textcolor{red}{-2}                                                                                                         &                                                                                                        &                                                                                      \\ \hline
    \textcolor{red}{-2.1634 + 1.2490i }                                                                                   & \textcolor{red}{-3}                                                                                                         
&                                                                                                        &                                                                                      
\\ \hline
    \textcolor{red}{-2.7     }                                                                              
   & \textcolor{red}{-4}                                                                                                         
      &                                                                                                        
       &                                                                                      
    \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
 \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` I get

[image]

If you load `caption`, you may want to try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareCaptionFont{red}{\color{red}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[]
\centering\color{red} \captionsetup{labelfont={red},textfont=red}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \caption{Pole}
\label{table5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}OHO \\ MF \\ $P$\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}OYE\\ OME\\ $P$\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}RA\\ OY \\ M\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FR\\ MOO\\ $M$\end{tabular} \\\arrayrulecolor{red}  \hline
    $-1.5$                                                                        
              & $-2$                                                                                                         &                                                                                                        &                                                                                      \\ \hline
    $-2.1634 + 1.2490\,\mathrm{i}$                                                           
                            & $-3$                                                                                                         
&                                                                                                        &                                                                                      
\\ \hline
    $-2.7$                                                                              
   & $-4$                                                                                                         
      &                                                                                                        
       &                                                                                      
    \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
 \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow when I try to compile this table in my complete document I am not getting it. But when I compile it individually alone I  get the red color in "Table 1:". Seems like might be some package clash or something like that

Comment: @ShiS Do you load the `caption` package? At least when I add `\usepackage{caption}` I also get a black caption.

Comment: Yes, I  had loaded it. When I remove it, "Table 1" is coming in red, but a few other errors are coming. Isn't it possible to do it while using caption package

Comment: @ShiS I added a proposal for that as well. (Of course you may want to drop some `\textcolor` commands and typeset the numbers in math mode and use `\mathrm{i}` for the imaginary `i`.)

Comment: This gives me exactly the output I wanted. Thanks. I have also dropped the redundant commands